# Display on the page the process from inside a function

Tags: javascript

I try to learn javascript and I got to chapter recursive functions. I want to print on the page the same thing that I see in console.log(isPalindrome('racecar')).

```
text.substr(1, text.length - 2) aceca
text.substr(1, text.length - 2) cec
text.substr(1, text.length - 2) e
```

```js
function isPalindrome(text) {
 if(text.length <= 1) {
  return true;
 }
 if(text.charAt(0) != text.charAt(text.length - 1)) {
  return false;
 }
 console.log("text.substr(1, text.length - 2)", text.substr(1, text.length - 2));
 
 return isPalindrome(text.substr(1, text.length - 2));
}


var form = document.getElementById("palindrome");
var formInput = document.getElementById("palindromeText").value;

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
 document.getElementById("preCode").innerHTML = isPalindrome(formInput);
});
```

```css
html, body, input, select, textarea{
    font-size: 1.05em !important;
}
h4 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <h2 class="text-primary text-center">Palindrome Text</h2>
         <form name="palindrome" id="palindrome">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="palindromeText" />
          </div>
          <buton id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Check text</buton>
      </form>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   
   <div id="preCode" class="code">
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="palindrome.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So right now doesn't work unless you modify the code and add manually isPalindrome('yourText). 
I put in the top how is show me the process in the console.log. I tried, without success, for my knowledge, to do the same, but to have the display in the page not console.log.

Can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: Did you include the javascript in the html file? Include in the head section

Comment: Yes, but I put here the code I deleted  the script tag by accident.

Comment: Ok consol.log the form input value and see if it is undefined

Comment: Why I have to put it in the top? If I put it in top the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your palindrome.js file is not being loaded properly. When I try to run the snippet on this page I see this error message in the console:

[image]

How are you hosting these files?

You may need to provide the path to palindrome.js in order for it to be properly loaded. If both index.html and palindrome.js are in the same directory, try this:

`<script src="./palindrome.js"></script>`

PS- it would be easier for us to help you if you post a link to a plunkr or something where we can edit and fiddle with the underlying source code.